When defining the surface integral of a vector field, why do we use the UNIT normal vector?
I am self-studying Vector Calculus by Corral. On page 158, definition 4.3, he goes through the intuition of a surface integral for a scalar field, which leads to his definition:

Makes total sense to me, no issue here. Two pages later he talks about surface integrals of a vector field. He goes straight into the definition:

Now, I have no issue with the fact that he didn't explain why he choose the outward vector (I am no engineer, I am simply doing this for fun, but I know this has to do with the flux, and so the outward measure is what we are interested in).
However, he says to use the UNIT outward normal vector in this formula, but he does not say why. There is no intuition given as to why the normal vector has to be a unit vector. I know that for any normal vector N, cN is also a normal vector, so I am guessing that it has to be standardized to something to avoid an infinite number of solutions being correct for the surface integral. But since I am doing this for leisure and not to get the answer right on a test, it's hard for me to move on from this definition without understanding where it came from.
All help is appreciated :)

Briefly, the component magnitude of a vector $F$ along a non-zero vector $v$ is $F \cdot v/|v|$. If $n = v/|v|$ is the unit vector positively proportional to $v$, this is $F \cdot n$. If $F$ is a vector field along an oriented surface, its flux is the integral of the component magnitudes relative to surface area.

right, but why?

The definition used is the same as calculating the flux. When you take a dot product of a vector with a unit vector, you essentially calculate the length of the projection ($|v|\cos(\theta)$). Intuitively, $F\cdot \hat{n}$ is how much the vector field points outwards.
